# How do I fill a dictionary with indices in a for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a transposed Dataframe tr:

|  | 7128 | 8719 | 14051 | 14636 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JDUTC_0 | 2451957.36 | 2452149.36 | 2457243.98 | 2452531.89 |
| JDUTC_1 | 2451957.37 | 2452149.36 | 2457243.99 | 2452531.90 |
| JDUTC_2 | 2451957.37 | 2452149.36 | 2457244.00 | 2452531.91 |
| JDUTC_3 | NaN | 2452149.36 | NaN | NaN |
| JDUTC_4 | NaN | 2452149.36 | NaN | NaN |
| JDUTC_5 | NaN | 2452149.36 | NaN | NaN |
| JDUTC_6 | 1.23 | 2452149.37 | NaN | NaN |
| JDUTC_7 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| JDUTC_8 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| JDUTC_9 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

And I create dict 'a' with this block of code:

```
a = {}
b=[]
for _, contents in tr.items():
    b.clear()
    for ind, val in enumerate(contents):
        if np.isnan(val):
            b.append(ind)
            continue
        else:
            pass
    print(_)
    print(b)
    a[_] = b
    print(a)
```

Which gives me this output:

```
7128
[3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
{7128: [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]}
8719
[7, 8, 9]
{7128: [7, 8, 9], 8719: [7, 8, 9]}
14051
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
{7128: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 8719: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 14051: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
14636
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
{7128: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 8719: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 14051: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
14636: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
```

What I expect dict 'a' to look like is this:

```
{7128: [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9]
 8719: [7, 8, 9]
14051: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
14636: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
```

What I am doing wrong?  Why is `a[_] = b` overwriting all the previous keys when `print(_)` is verifying that _ is always the next column label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the correct name convention, I would change your code
after:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

s = StringIO("""idx 7128    8719    14051   14636
JDUTC_0 2451957.36  2452149.36  2457243.98  2452531.89
JDUTC_1 2451957.37  2452149.36  2457243.99  2452531.90
JDUTC_2 2451957.37  2452149.36  2457244.00  2452531.91
JDUTC_3 NaN 2452149.36  NaN NaN
JDUTC_4 NaN 2452149.36  NaN NaN
JDUTC_5 NaN 2452149.36  NaN NaN
JDUTC_6 1.23    2452149.37  NaN NaN
JDUTC_7 NaN NaN NaN NaN
JDUTC_8 NaN NaN NaN NaN
JDUTC_9 NaN NaN NaN NaN""")

tr = pd.read_csv(s, sep="\t", index_col=0)
```

(people should give minimal working code - but often forget to give e.g. the code to build the data frame etc. and the imports)

to:

```
a = {}
b = []
for name, values in tr.items():
    b.clear() # this is problematic as you know
    for ind, val in enumerate(values):
        if np.isnan(val):
            b.append(ind)
            continue
        else:
            pass
    a[name] = b
```

`continue` and `pass` are not necessary - they just say "go on" with the loop.
In Python, you are not forced to give the `else` branch:

```
for name, values in tr.items():
    b.clear() # This is still problematic at this state.
    for ind, val in enumerate(values):
        if np.isnan(val):
            b.append(ind)
    a[name] = b
```

Such collection of data using for-loops are better done with list-comprehensions:

```
a = {}
for name, values in tr.items():
    b = [ind for ind, val in enumerate(values) if np.isnan(val)]
    a[name] = b
# now the result is already correct!
```

And finally, you can even build list-comprehensions for dictionaries -
making this entire code a one-liner - but a readable one - when one is familiar with list comprehensions:

```
a = {name: [i for i, x in enumerate(vals) if np.isnan(x)] for name, vals in tr.items()}
```

You can see the result:

```
a
# which returns:
{'7128': [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9],
 '8719': [7, 8, 9],
 '14051': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 '14636': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
```

List-comprehensions are going into the direction of Functional Programming (FP).
Which exactly deals with the problem of not to apply mutation (like the `b.append()` or `b.clear()` methods - because - as you have seen: your case is a demonstration of how easily a bug is generated when using mutation. - and would contribute to the discussion - why FP - while it at the first sight looks brain-unfriendly - is
actually the more brain-friendly way to program.

List comprehensions are the Pythonic form of "map" - and if you use a "if" inside list comprehensions - this is the Pythonic equivalent to "filter" which FP people know like a second brain for breathing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are assigning same list to all keys.

```
a = {}
b=[] # < --- You create one Array/list 'b'
for _, contents in tr.items():
    b.clear()
    for ind, val in enumerate(contents):
        if np.isnan(val):
            b.append(ind)
            continue
        else:
            pass
    print(_)
    print(b)
    a[_] = b # <-- assign same array to all keys.
    print(a)
```

Check my comment on the code above.

```
b.clear()
```

This line just clears the same array, it does not create a new array.

To run the code as you intended, create a new array/list in side the loop.

```
a = {}
for _, contents in tr.items():
    b = [] # <--- new array/list is created
    for ind, val in enumerate(contents):
        if np.isnan(val):
            b.append(ind)
            continue
        else:
            pass
    print(_)
    print(b)
    a[_] = b # <--- Now you assign the new array 'b' to a[_]
    print(a)
```

Comment: The convention is to use '_' only if you don't use it. maybe `i` for index is better.

Comment: Awsome, thank you thats exactly what I needed. But I still don't understand why it didn't work before.  On every iteration _ changed to the next column label, And print(b) was showing that it was populated with a different set of numbers.  Why didn't the key change? How does creating a new list on every iteration prevent that from happening? I thought creating a new list on every iteration was bad practice?

Comment: Firstly, @Gwang-JinKim is correct about the convention. Use `_` only if you don't use the variable anywhere else in the code. Although your code with `_` is technically correct, it just does not fit the convention.

Comment: Secondly, the problem with your code was not that the key `_` was not updating but that you were using the same value (array `b`) to set to the dictionary. a `List` is a mutable variable, meaning you can update it, but its identity remains the same. Your intention is to create a new list for every key, so you must do that inside the loop. In your code, you just created one list at the beginning `b = []`, and just updated it and assigned that as value to all the keys.

Comment: I think I understand now.  So because a `List` is mutable every time it's changed it updates in all instances of the variable because they all point back to the same memory space, `id(b)`.  But when I create a new `List` the old `b` is cleared and a new memory space is pointed to. So when I populate the dictionary every `value` points to a new memory space.

Comment: Python is in that matter quite imperative (means - it does "call by reference" and not "call by value") - your problem just is your start to encounter this "problem" with Python. - well it is not a problem per se. Imperative languages - like Python - have to rely on this - otherwise performance would be even slower than it is.